# How to run signtool.exe on Linux enivironment

Tags: linux, sign, bin

I want to run below command with signtool.exe on Linux environment. I know signtool.exe is windows command, but I need to run it on Linux... Could you tell me how to if someone knows?

```
signtool.exe sign /fd sha256 /p7 .\ /p7co 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 /p7ce DetachedSignedData /a /f .\PK.PFX /p <password> SigList_Serialization.bin
```

I refer here..

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to install wine? You can create a bat file and execute using wine.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, and I can't run windows tool itself on some reason ( our company policy) .... so, I want to know Linux tool to sign bin file with equivalent effective on Windows environment...

Comment: Are you trying to sign PE (Windows) binaries or ELF (Linux) binaries?  We need to know more about what kind of file you want to sign and what kind of signature you want (e.g., does it need to be verified by the system when running the program or is a separate tool okay?).

Comment: I'm trying to sign certificate binary and trying to generate PKCS7# file which was signed by private key. sign with sha256 and includes OID. Is it enough for your question?

Comment: You can use either Jsign https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/ or https://github.com/mtrojnar/osslsigncode which both are doing what you're asking.

Also I'm downvoting your question as you clearly didn't search properly